# How to assign keydown events to a userform?

Tags: excel, vba, userform, keydown

I want specific keys (Enter, Right Arrow, Esc) to execute different procedures.

I have the following code but nothing is working. I tried setting KeyPreview = True, but that did not seem to change anything.

```
Sub UserForm1_KeyDown(ByVal KeyAscii As MSForms.ReturnInteger, ByVal Shift As Integer)
    Select Case KeyAscii
        Case 13 'enter key
            addBtn_Click
        Case 39 'right arrow
            skipBtn_Click
        Case 27 'escape key
            exitBtn_Click
        Case Else
    End Select
End Sub
```

UPDATE
Chris mentioned (below) that it should be named after the class, readjusting names helped fix some other small bugs in my form. However I've run into an issue with having the userform open on a command button click, running or clicking this gives me a 1004 error.

```
Private Sub blocksSorter_Click()
     Load UserForm1
     UserForm1.Show
End Sub
```

Comment: Is the name of your form `UserForm1`? If not, that would explain it. Then it would just be a subroutine which may as well be called "Nichole" that is never triggered by anything. When you click inside the routine and look at the dropdowns at the top of the VBA editor, do you see `UserForm1` in the left one and `KeyDown` in the right one? or does the left one say `(General)`?

Comment: Hi, yes my form is called UserForm1. In the VBA editor, the left one says (General) and right shows UserForm1_KeyDown

Comment: Both of those things cannot be true. If it says `(General)` then it's not tied to any event. Double click on the form itself, that will open the form's `Click` event, then using the right dropdown, change it to `KeyDown` - That is where the code should be. Maybe you mistakenly put the code in a Module?

Comment: Ok, tried doing that and putting the code  there where the editor shows UserForm and KeyDown. But that doesnt seem to do the trick.

Comment: Well it works just fine for me... you didnt try and put the Sub definition inside the sub definition, did you? try just putting the word `Stop` in the event to see if the editor stops there. There is something you are not understanding about all of this.

Comment: I think it might be referencing the wrong name. So, even though I have named my form UserForm1, it still shows as UserForm on the drop down, so when clicking into my routine in the editor it shows as (General) rather than UserForm or UserForm1. Do you know a workaround for this?

Comment: Ttry just putting the word `Stop` in the event to see if the editor stops there. Dont use the code you are trying to get working yet.

Comment: Does not stop  there

Comment: Assuming you put `Stop` in the right place and then pressed a key when the form had focus, there is still something you are doing wrong. The problem isn't your code, it's your understanding of how events work.

Comment: im going to test this out on an entirely new form, thanks for your suggestions so far

Comment: That was my next recommendation.

Comment: The name of your event _should_ be `Sub UserForm_KeyDown( ...` (Note, no `1`).  The Form Events are named after the Class, not the Instance.

Comment: Thanks gents, I've added an update to my question above... Made sure all my events are named after the Class, but Ive run into an issue with loading and show the userform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not matter how you name your Userform, the event always has the name `Userform_event` as said in one of the comments. And you have to put the code into the class module of the userform. In this case

```
Sub UserForm_KeyDown(ByVal KeyAscii As MSForms.ReturnInteger, ByVal Shift As Integer)
    Select Case KeyAscii
        Case 13 'enter key
            addBtn_Click
        Case 39 'right arrow
            skipBtn_Click
        Case 27 'escape key
            exitBtn_Click
        Case Else
    End Select
End Sub
```

This [article](https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-user-forms-1/) gives a quite good overview and introduction to userforms